# How to execute conditionally based on environment variable in Java?

Tags: java, spring, yaml, development-environment, production-environment

I have a simple validation in a block (let's say Login method) and I want to omit or run this block differently for development environment in Java:

```
@Value("${security.validation.myParam}")
private boolean myParam;

public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<UserDTO>> login(LoginRequest request
    ) throws IOException {
    if(validator.isValid())) {
        //
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, how should I omit or execute differently the `if(validator.isValid())` line based on environment value (`myParam`)?

Comment: Sounds clunky. Are you *really* prepared to take down a running instance (which you'd have to do) to change an environment variable, even if it's just for testing purposes?

Comment: @g00se Sorry, but I do not understand what do you mean. Any clarification pls?

Comment: I mean, the environment is as it is when you start your software. If you want to change that environment (e.g. to change/add a variable), you need to restart that software.

Comment: Actually I just want to omit a validation during development phase and if I set this using `development`  environment (local), ı do not have to make settings for that purpose for everyday. Assume that, you have a login page, but you want to omit it while development. To fill the email, password field is easy, but **what about providing a token**? In this case you will have to omit the token validation or check block. And think of that you perform this at backend side. Any idea?

Comment: Well if that's your use case, there are various ways of doing that. e.g. check for a 'validation file'.

Comment: It seems like `if (myParam) { /* existing code */ } else { /* other code */ }` is an obvious answer. However if that was the answer, you probably wouldn't ask here. Can you edit the question so that it is obvious that this is not the answer?

Comment: @flyx Thanks a lot. Yes, you right. Actually I thought exactly the same thing. But I am not sure if it is a good approach or if there is a better approach for this situation. Any help pls?

Comment: You could use `@Profile` and `@Autowired` to inject different validator implementations in the different environments, [see here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles). What is a good approach and what is not depends on your project and can not definitely be answered on StackOverflow.